# Python connection to Mysql via SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Need assistance to figure out an issue while connecting to MySQL via SQLALCHEMY.
Below is what I tried :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas

def return_connection_string(database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port):
    try:
        connection_string = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://' + database_user + ':' + database_password + '@' + database_host + ':' + database_port + '/' + database_name
        print(connection_string)
        return connection_string
    except Exception as e:
        print('Encountered error while generating connection string for MySQL!')
        print(e)

def return_connection_object(database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port):
    try:
        connection_string = return_connection_string(database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port)
        engine = create_engine(connection_string).connect()
        return engine
    except Exception as e:
        print('Encountered error while connecting to MySQL database!')
        print(e)


mysql_conn = return_connection_object('db_name', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'xyz.abc.com', '4100')


df = pandas.read_sql_query('select distinct table_name  from information_schema.tables', mysql_conn)
print(df.shape)


mysql_conn.close()
```

The above script works perfectly fine and returns the desired output.
The issue is when I try a class based approach as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import logging


class Connection_class(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def return_connection_string(self, database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port):
        try:
            connection_string = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://' + database_user + ':' + database_password + '@' + database_host + ':' + database_port + '/' + database_name
            print(connection_string)
            return connection_string
        except Exception as e:
            print('Encountered error while generating connection string for MySQL!')
            print(e)

    def return_connection_object(self, database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port):
        try:
            connection_string = self.return_connection_string(database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port)
            engine = create_engine(connection_string).connect()            
            return engine
        except Exception as e:
            print('Encountered error while connecting to MySQL database!')
            print(e)
```

I wrapped the above class in a package called mysql. The main.py is as below:

```
from mysql import connector
import pandas 

mysql_obj = connector()
mysql_conn = mysql_obj.return_connection_object('db_name', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'xyz.abc.com', '4100')


df = pandas.read_sql_query('select distinct table_name  from information_schema.tables', mysql_conn)

mysql_conn.close()
```

The error I get is :
**type object 'Connection_class' has no attribute 'paramstyle'**

On debugging i found the error originating from return_connection_object function, somehow it is returning null while the exact same function returns a connection object when ran as a script.

Any leads would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The name you use for the package seems quite generic and may conflict with some other `connnector`. May try renaming your module and object imported to eliminate this possible source of error.